# Change Package Name of Android App

Tags: eclipse, apk, package-name

I am a complete noobs about android apps. So you will have to completely guide me through everything.

I tried to Install the Clock app from the KitKat factory Image but it wont Install. I'm shown the error "An existing package by the same name with a conflicting signature is already installed". Now will I be able to install it after changing the package name.?

If so, how can i change the package name.? I already have Eclipse SDK but i don't know how to use it.. Please guide me..

Answer (score 0):

ofcourse, you can do. follow below steps:
1) right click on application project name.
2)Move your mouse  cursor to "Android Tools" from pop up options.
3)Select "Rename Application Package" and follow the steps.

you are done.

Hopefully it will be helpful to you.